# lighttpd - use different document-root for diff url

Tags: lighttpd

To me this seem logical, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)hd.domain\.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/domain_site/"

    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/aa/" {
      server.document-root = "/domain_aa_site/"
    }

}
```

When I go to http://hd.domain.com/aa/ I get "404 - Not Found"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Why don't you just put an "aa" subolfer inside "/domain_site/" ?

Comment: I want to link to several different folders, some on other hard drives, I have created a few different sub domains, but it would be much easier to just add fake folders as above...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for lighttpd's `mod_alias`.

Something like this:

```
alias.url = (
  "/aa" => "/domain_aa_site/"
  "/somewhere/else" => "/other/docroot/"
)
```